# Same screen with different Nested Json array data in React-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to display same screen with different parameter in react-native. i checked with https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/navigate-with-params-v3. its working fine. But i have to display the different data in same screen.  My expectation is in tree view structure data have to display like in our normal system tile view folder structure.

Expected Output view:
The view like normal our system folder title structure. C:/user/ReactNative/file .. like tile view.

Ex:
1.FamilyScreen.js
params : Gradpa -> while click Grandpa it will navigate to same page but the data change as 'Father'

2. FamilyScreen.js
   params:Me - While click 'Father' it will navigate to same page but the data as 'Erick and Rose'.

The data will come from service so it may contain some more than children. it will variant. How to pass the particular data in react-native.

```
const family = [
  {
    id: 'Grandparent',
    name: 'Grandpa',
    age: 78,
    children: [
      {
        id: 'Father',
        name: 'Father',
        age: 30,
        children: [
          {
            id: 'Erick',
            name: 'Erick',
            age: 10,
          },
          {
            id: 'Rose',
            name: 'Rose',
            age: 12,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Thanks

Comment: You should use your state to store the data, and set the selected "state" children when the user clicks an item. Then you use that selected state (children) as your data for display. Read more about state management here - https://www.sitepoint.com/state-management-in-react-native/

Answer (score 0):

Finaly its working, here my code is

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)    
        this.state = {
             res:family,               
        }           
        this.getNestedData = this.getNestedData.bind(this);
    }    
getNestedData (item)  {      
         var data;
                  Object.keys(item).map((propKey) => {
                    if ( propKey === 'children'){            
                        data=item[propKey]                   

                }

            })


            this.props.navigation.push('GridScreen',{
                data:data
            });

        }

        Item = ({ item }) => {

            return (
                <View style={styles.item}>
                    <Text style={styles.title} onPress={this.getNestedData.bind(this,item)}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            );
        }
        render() {
            const { navigation } = this.props;
        const data = navigation.getParam('data', this.state.res);

            return (
                <View>
                    <FlatList
                        data={data }
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <this.Item item={item} />}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                        numColumns={3}
                    />

                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```