# JSON tree like structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

```
{
    "squadName": "Super hero squad",
    "homeTown": "Metro City",
    "formed": 2016,
    "secretBase": "Super tower",
    "active": true,
    "members": [
        {
            "name": "Molecule Man",
            "age": 29,
            "secretIdentity": "Dan Jukes",
            "powers": [
                "Radiation resistance",
                "Turning tiny",
                "Radiation blast"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Madame Uppercut",
            "age": 39,
            "secretIdentity": "Jane Wilson",
            "powers": [
                "Million tonne punch",
                "Damage resistance",
                "Superhuman reflexes"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Eternal Flame",
            "age": 1000000,
            "secretIdentity": "Unknown",
            "powers": [
                "Immortality",
                "Heat Immunity",
                "Inferno",
                "Teleportation",
                "Interdimensional travel"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to iterate each single data and display on react want to know about logic this above data is not fixed and every time is different key and value pairs but accourding to data it changes and shows on frontend and also checkbox with parent child hierarchy

Comment: Please explain better what you need, maybe write the desired output

Comment: duplicate: [How to handle recursive array mapping with React components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198606/how-to-handle-recursive-array-mapping-with-react-components) or [How to have nested loops with map in JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402365/how-to-have-nested-loops-with-map-in-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

To iterate and display the given data in a React component, you can use the .map() function on arrays.

```js
// setup the data
const data = {
    squadName: "Super hero squad",
    homeTown: "Metro City",
    formed: 2016,
    secretBase: "Super tower",
    active: true,
    members: [
        //rest
    ]
};
```

```js
import React from 'react';

function SquadDetails() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.squadName}</h1>
            <p>Home Town: {data.homeTown}</p>
            <p>Formed: {data.formed}</p>
            <p>Secret Base: {data.secretBase}</p>
            <p>Active: {data.active ? "Yes" : "No"}</p>
            
            <h2>Members:</h2>
            {data.members.map((member, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <h3>{member.name}</h3>
                    <p>Age: {member.age}</p>
                    <p>Secret Identity: {member.secretIdentity}</p>
                    <ul>
                        {member.powers.map((power, powerIndex) => (
                            <li key={powerIndex}>{power}</li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default SquadDetails;
```

The main logic here involves:

Displaying the non-array data directly using JSX curly braces. Using the .map() function to iterate over the members array and display each member's details. Within each member's details, using another .map() function to display the list of powers. With this approach, even if the data structure changes (like adding more members or powers), the React component will dynamically adjust to display the new data.

Comment: actually the json data is not fixed it comes randomly so this method cant work